# Problem with adding click listener to list element in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am fiddling around with vue, and for some reason am not able to add a click event listener to a `<li>`

HTML:

```
<div id="example">
  <vue-navbar></vue-navbar>
  <nav-drawer v-bind:open="open">
    <div slot="drawer-content">
      <ul class="nav flex-column" id="DrawerItems">

        <li class="nav-item" v-on:click="DoShowHome">
            <a class="nav-link" >
                <i class="ion-ios-home"></i> Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" v-on:click="DoShowStatistics">
            <a class="nav-link" >
                <i class="ion-stats-bars"></i> Statistics
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" v-on:click="DoShowActivity">
            <a class="nav-link" >
                <i class="ion-flash"></i> Activity
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" v-on:click="DoShowSettings">
            <a class="nav-link" >
                <i class="ion-gear-b"></i> Settings
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div slot="main-content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="app-content">
                <div v-if="ShowHome">ShowHome</div>
                <div v-if="ShowStatistics">ShowStatistics</div>
                <div v-if="ShowActivity">ShowActivity</div>
                <div v-if="ShowSettings">ShowSettings</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav-drawer>
</div>
```

with the script.js containing the following vue component:

```
var example = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: function(){
    return {
        open: true,
        ShowHome: true,
        ShowStatistics: false,
        ShowActivity:false,
        ShowSettings:false
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    messageBroker.$on('toggle-nav-drawer', this.toggleDrawer)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    messageBroker.$off('toggle-nav-drawer', this.toggleDrawer)
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDrawer: function() {
      this.open = !this.open;
    },
    DoShowHome: function(event){
        this.ShowHome = true;
        this.ShowStatistics = false;
        this.ShowActivity = false;
        this.ShowSettings = false;
    },
    DoShowStatistics: function(event){
        this.ShowHome = false;
        this.ShowStatistics = true;
        this.ShowActivity = false;
        this.ShowSettings = false;
    },
    DoShowActivity: function(event){
        this.ShowHome = false;
        this.ShowStatistics = false;
        this.ShowActivity = true;
        this.ShowSettings = false;
    },
    DoShowSettings: function(event){
        this.ShowHome = false;
        this.ShowStatistics = false;
        this.ShowActivity = false;
        this.ShowSettings = true;
    }
  }
});
```

I am probably doing this wrong, but for the life of me after finding dozens of tutorials I am not able to reproduce a working onclick method. Console isn't telling me anything either.

The idea is that I will later create the content of the fields that are dependant on those "Show*" variables, and when i call the function from console by calling

```
example.DoShowActivity()
```

It does display the other div. What am i missing?

Comment: [Here's a code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEQgqo) to get you going in the right direction

Comment: where are you define `messageBroker`?